# Filling Data in qlikview

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I'm trying to fill each month with all the units and '0' for the missing unit, can anyone help me on this
Actual data:

```html
LOAD * Inline [
Unit,Month,Sold
7511,Sep 2020,13000
7512,Sep 2020,10000
7511,Nov 2020,7500
7513,Dec 2020,5000
7511,Dec 2020,7100
];
```

Expected:

| Unit | Month | Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7511 | Sep 2020 | 13000 |
| 7512 | Sep 2020 | 10000 |
| 7513 | Sep 2020 | 0 |
| 7511 | Nov 2020 | 7500 |
| 7512 | Nov 2020 | 0 |
| 7513 | Nov 2020 | 0 |
| 7511 | Dec 2020 | 7100 |
| 7512 | Dec 2020 | 0 |
| 7513 | Dec 2020 | 5000 |

Answer (score 0):

Create a calendar table that includes all your date(Month) values. Then, left join distinct list of your units to populate data. After that left join your existing data and lastly, use load-resident to recall your table write

```
if( isnull(Sold), 0, Sold) as Sold
```

Don't forget to drop old table.

Here is a link about creating a calendar table: [enter link description here](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-App-Dev/Creating-A-Master-Calendar/td-p/341286)